# Infragistics State Button Checked doesn't show borders

Tags: background, onclick, border, infragistics

Here is my question. I have some state button tools in my Toolbars Manager. When I set Checked = True, I don't see that button is checked. Actually I see it, but without borders as usual. Instead of that I can see light-light blue background in my state button tool. Could you please answer why is it happen and how can I change my code to view state button checked state as usual (with borders and usual background) ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your problem setting the `BorderAlpha` property to `Transparent`.
Resetting to Default reenables the border around the Tool.

The property is present in every Appearance settings of the button, but the one I have used is the `PressedAppearance` of the Tool (Large or Small depending on your customization)